# PHP Multi level JSON Pull/Retrieve

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having a little trouble grabbing data from JSON code.  I am trying to grab "Message" value under "innererror" from the json code which is "entity : An error has occurred."

```
$json = '{
  "odata.error":{
        "code":"",
        "message":{
            "lang":"en-US",
            "value":"The request is invalid."
            },
        "innererror":{
            "message":"entity : An error has occurred.",
            "type":"",
            "stacktrace":""
            }
  }
}';
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

$main_response_data = $json_data['innererror'];


echo $main_response_data[0]['message'];
```

Comment: Change it to `$main_response_data = $json_data['odata.error']['innererror'];` and `echo $main_response_data['message'];`. You will have to learn a bit more about objects and arrays.

Comment: Thank you for that!  :-)  I was reading over this ( https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/php/205/php-nested-json.html )

Comment: See demo https://onlinephp.io/c/bf45d